# i cannot set GOPATH to blank

Tags: go

**macOS Big Sur 11.6.8**

i read from the official docs that the GOPATH variable should not be used by non-Go maintainers. so i tried to empty it from CLI:

```
export GOPATH=""
```

and then checking my environment variables:

```
echo $GOPATH
```

shows it is indeed empty. however, upon checking Go's environment variables:

```
go env
```

it shows GOPATH having a default value of $HOME/go

i thought that was odd. since i installed golang using brew, i thought maybe something wrong with brew's version. so i uninstalled golang using brew and installed golang again this time using the binaries from [go.dev](https://go.dev)

*same problem.*

i want all my source files, object files, executable files to temporarily reside in my project's directory. how can i do that with golang?

Comment: Read [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code).

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to get your object files in a different location. Source files? Put them wherever you want (within reason), if you have a go.mod file then you don't need to do anything else. Executable files? Use `go build` instead of `go install` and the output will be in your working directory. But object files are intended to be in a common place, shared amongst all your other projects' object files for speed and reuse.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn you are absolutely right!

Comment: You can use `go mod vendor` to put all your imported packages' source in your project folder, but I don't think that moves object files.

Comment: Maybe you could try something like `go env -w GOPATH=`

Comment: You may not use GOPATH directly, but there must be one set, which is why there is a default. What problem are you trying solve?